# SwiftUI Software keyboard + two TextFields = Constraint conflict

Tags: ios, keyboard, swiftui, nslayoutconstraint

**TL;DR**

Tapping a second `TextField` while the keyboard is showing triggers a constraint conflict.

**Details**

The code below is runnable as-is. Tap the top `TextField`, then the one below. The Xcode console reports this (abridged for clarity):

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 

    <'assistantHeight' TUISystemInputAssistantView.height == 44   (active)>
    <'assistantView.bottom' TUISystemInputAssistantView.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView.top   (active)>
    <'assistantView.top' V:|-(0)-[TUISystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: '|':UIInputSetHostView )>
    <'inputView.top' V:|-(0)-[_UIKBCompatInputView]   (active, names: '|':UIInputSetHostView )>

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <'assistantView.bottom' ...>
```

**Questions**

AFAIK I have no control over any of the four constraints. Is there a way to avoid this? Should I even worry?

**Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text1 = ""
    @State private var text2 = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Tap here first...", text: $text1)
            .background(Color.white).padding()

            TextField("...then tap here", text: $text2)
            .background(Color.white).padding()

            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you resolve it yet?
if not maybe this would help!

```
GeometryReader.init { geometry in
        ScrollView.init {
            VStack.init(alignment: .leading, spacing: nil, content: {
                Text("Hello.")
                    .font(.custom("Helvetica-Bold", size: 32))
                Text("This just my sample application using swift UI")
                    .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: (geometry.size.width * 0.35)))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                TextField.init("Email Address", text: self.$textFieldName)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 50)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .layoutPriority(1000)
                TextField.init("Email Address", text: self.$textFieldName)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 50)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .layoutPriority(1000)
            })
        }
    }
```

if you curious what happens to you constraints its because your keyboard had autocorrection in it.

using this line,
`.disableAutocorrection(<#Bool?#>)`
get rid of your autocorreaction tab in the top of your keyboard.

Comment: Thank you, adding the modifier to either of the TextFields prevented the complaint. And showed me that the "offending" part of the keyboard view was the autocorrect pane at the top.